# Plotly (R) Makes a small number the largest bar in a bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I have a bar chart with y values of 2%, then 11, 13, etc. with a max of 18%. For some reason, R is displaying my value of 2% as the full height of the graph (with its value above 18 on the y axis label) so it looks very weird. Any suggestions to help?
 [image: Here's the current result]

Here is my code

```
age_data <- read.csv("age data.csv")
a <- list(
  autotick = FALSE,
  ticks = "outside",
  tick0 = 0,
  dtick = 0.25,
  ticklen = 5,
  tickwidth = 2,
  tickcolor = toRGB("blue")
)

fig <- plot_ly(data = age_data, x = ~Age, y = ~PerCases, type = 'bar', text = ~PerCases, textposition = 'auto')
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = a, yaxis = a)
fig
```

It's quite similar to the documentation, I know. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It was fixed by changing the data of  "2%" to "02%". If anyone has a reason why this works rather than just "2%" I'd like to know!

Comment: Your y-values are strings (or maybe factors) and not numbers. Convert to a numeric value and then format the y-axis accordingly.